# Do we have FilteringSelect module in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Do we have a component in angularjs which works as both input text and a drop down much like FilteringSelect component of dojo.

https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/selects_using_stores/demo/ProgFilteringSelect.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are  a number of [autocomplete modules](http://ngmodules.org/tags/autocomplete) available for angularjs. You would probably want to choose the one which matches your preference.

[Here](https://axelzarate.wordpress.com/2014/07/31/custom-dropdown-autocomplete-with-angularjs/) is one I think almost similar to your requirement,here's the [github](https://github.com/axel-zarate/js-custom-select)  for the example.

[Here](https://github.com/Siyfion/angular-typeahead) is one more - typeahead with autocomplete. You can style it to your preference.

HTH!